# how to pass GET parameters with Flask using add_url_rule

Tags: python, flask

beginner's question:
is it possible to pass **GET** request parameters to a route function in Flask using `add_url_rule`?

I am getting the error message that the `verify_username_route` function I declare later (that takes 1 parameter) is called without any parameters passed.

```
self.application_.add_url_rule(self.path_ + '/verify', 'verify', self.verify_username_route, methods=['GET'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fetch query string parameters, you use `request.args.get('argname')` in your function.  Nothing is passed in -- it's all done through the globals.

Answer (score 0):

To pass any parameters in your URLs, you can use Flask's built-in patterns. These work for both `@app.route` decorators and `add_url_route` methods. Here is your code, with a parameter:

```py
self.application_.add_url_rule(self.path_ + '/verify/<int:val>', 'verify', self.verify_username_route, methods=['GET'])
```

The important part from this is the exact route: `/verify/<int:parameter>`. This tells Flask that you want the route to be in the format of `/verify/something`, where something is any integer. Whatever integer is entered here when the request is made gets passed to your `self.verify_username_route` as a parameter called `val`.

Read more about this [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/#variable-rules).